# GPL v3 "convey" vs. GPL v2 "distribute"

Tags: licensing, gpl, terminology

I've noticed that the [GNU GPL version 3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) uses the word "convey" where [version 2](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html) used "distriubte":

GNU GPLv3:

> To “convey” a work means any kind of propagation that enables other parties to make or receive copies. Mere interaction with a user through a computer network, with no transfer of a copy, is not conveying.

GNU GPLv2:

> To protect your rights, we need to make restrictions that forbid anyone to deny you these rights or to ask you to surrender the rights. These restrictions translate to certain responsibilities for you if you distribute copies of the software, or if you modify it.

Is “convey” in GPLv3 the same thing as what GPLv2 means by “distribute”?

Comment: This is covered by the GPL FAQ (https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#ConveyVsDistribute). The answer is: Yes.

Comment: @ArtOfCode From the `licensing` tag description: "Only use this tag if your question concerns the application of a license to an area of interest." Are you sure this is the case?

Comment: Yes, because the use of terms heavily affects the application of the license.

Comment: @EricGärtner That's a pretty confusing tag wiki, it should probably be fixed :/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [GPL FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#ConveyVsDistribute) states:

> **Is “convey” in GPLv3 the same thing as what GPLv2 means by
>   “distribute”?**
>
> Yes, more or less. During the course of enforcing GPLv2, we learned
>   that some jurisdictions used the word “distribute” in their own
>   copyright laws, but gave it different meanings. We invented a new term
>   to make our intent clear and avoid any problems that could be caused
>   by these differences.

So yes, they mean basically the same.

Comment: Link you posted leads to language autodetect site. Use english-enforced address: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#ConveyVsDistribute or the anchor to specific question won't work for people identified to use another language.

Comment: @Mołot The anchor has the same ID for other languages.  The link appears to work, even when I set my browser language to Spanish.

Comment: @Mołot: I agree with Max, the anchor is working in german too. I think the guys at gnu knew what they were doing.

Comment: OK, maybe it's broken only for Polish, then :/

Comment: It's broken for Polish? In that case I should change the link.

Comment: @jalanb: I don't know what you're talking about. GPL version 3 (but not version 2) absolutely does define "convey" in its definitions section, right next to all of the other definitions. (Version 2 need not define that term, because it does not use that term.)